# How to iterate through two lists with one of them shifted?

Tags: python

My question is how do you start one list at the next index when iterating?

```
for elem1, elem2 in zip(unigram_mixture_list, bigram_mixture_list):
    print elem1, elem2
```

I want to start looping through `elem1` one index ahead.

How would I achieve this in python?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it cleaner - there was some irrelevant information which clattered it and didn't really alter the meaning of the question (only obscured it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

slice the first list with `[1:]`:

```
for elem1, elem2 in zip(unigram_mixture_list[1:], bigram_mixture_list):
```

You got everything else exactly right

---

Note that if the lists were the same length, but now truncated because you've shortened one, you have a couple choices:

- slice the second list to remove the tail: `[:-1]`
- replace `zip` with `itertools.izip_longest` (after `import itertools`)

Example with `izip_longest`:

```
import itertools

# ~~~ other code ~~~ #

for elem1, elem2 in itertools.izip_longest(unigram_mixture_list[1:], bigram_mixture_list):
    print elem1, elem2
```

---

Edit: In python 3, `izip_longest` was renamed `zip_longest`, so use that instead.

Comment: thanks but just wondering why my post was edited by sashkello? Was it because it was too superfluous?

Comment: sorry I'm new to python, how would I achieve that? Sorry for the hand-holding :)

Comment: sorry again, let me rephrase my question, I was referring to your question about slicing it?....I need to iterate through all the elements in 2nd list, but skip the first element in the first list

Comment: hi mhlester, I received an error saying 'module' object has no attribute 'izip_longest

Comment: I'm in python 3.3.3 and problem solved, thank you for your patience sir!

Comment: it has been a pleasure. happy to be of assistance

Answer (score 2):

There is the `zip` approach, but if the lists are the same length the longer will be truncated:

```
>>> li1='abcdefg'
>>> li2='1234567'
>>> zip(li1[1:], li2)
[('b', '1'), ('c', '2'), ('d', '3'), ('e', '4'), ('f', '5'), ('g', '6')]
# NOTE -- '7' is dropped from li2...
```

With Python 2, you can use `map`:

```
>>> map(None, li1[1:], li2)
[('b', '1'), ('c', '2'), ('d', '3'), ('e', '4'), ('f', '5'), ('g', '6'), (None, '7')]
# NOTE -- We ran out of li1, so start using 'None'
```

For both Python 2 and 3, you can use [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) from itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> list(izip_longest(li1[1:], li2))
[('b', '1'), ('c', '2'), ('d', '3'), ('e', '4'), ('f', '5'), ('g', '6'), (None, '7')]
```

Comment: Woah, ninja secret nuance to `map`!

Comment: I can't promise I'll ever use or remember that, but +1 for learning!

Comment: @mhlester: You should actually forget you ever saw it -- the idiom no longer works in Python 3 unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) offers a tool for offsetting iterables called [`more_itertools.zip_offset`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.zip_offset):

```
import more_itertools as mit


it1 = "0123"
it2 = "abcdef"

for elem1, elem2 in mit.zip_offset(it1, it2, offsets=(1, 0), longest=True):
    print(elem1, elem2)
```

Output

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
None d
None e
None f
```

Notice the first iterable is offset by 1 element, as specified by the `offsets` keyword.  The optional keyword `longest` feeds a `fillvalue` until iteration is completed over the longest iterable.  For your application, simply substitute the iterables.